# Need to develop a data entry platform in MS Access using forms

Tags: database, forms, validation, ms-access, vba

So I've been given the task of developing a GUI for our data entry team that allows them to enter/update records that will then be appended to certain tabels within our database.

I'm having trouble planning the exception handling of flagging of certain events like a missing value that may be used to search for a record later, values that are too long/short to satisfy validation rules within the database, things like that.

Are there any resources or tips/advice you folks can provide that make exception handling and data entry easier? I know Access probably isn't the desired platform here, but I have no choice.

Comment: Have you tried VBA? Are you using a command button to execute an append or update? It should be as simple as referencing your controls and testing the values they contain. `IsNull([Me!MyField])`, `LEN(Me!MyField) > 255` are examples of expressions to use in `IF` statements in your command button click prior to running the append/update. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You can create these sort of validation rules directly for the form controls, no need to write code for it.

Comment: IsNull, as @ChristopherD said, is my preferred way to handle these situations.  You can develop a list of them in an If/ElseIf statement that will error check prior to entering the information into your database.